# How many different kinds of fruit does it take to mix 10 different fruit bags with 4 fruits in each?

Tags: combinatorics

I have difficulties even with how to classify the problem. Am I looking on a permutation or a combination? I think it is a combination because it's in a bag and therefore it has no order.
Also, which theorems, definitions etc.  can I use?

Comment: Are there 4 different fruits in each bag?

Comment: I do not think it matters. As long as there are 10 different bags with 4 fruits in each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that each bag contains $4$ **different fruits**, your question boils down to find the smallest $n$ such that 
$$\binom n4 \geq 10$$

Since, $\binom 54 = 5$, you may try $\binom 64 = \binom 62 = 15$. So $n=6$ is the solution in this case.

If the **fruits can be repeated**, you are looking for the smallest $n$ such that $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots +x_n = 4$ has at least $10$ different solutions.

$$\binom{n+4-1}{4} = \binom {n+3}{4} \geq 10$$

Here, $n=3$ is the solution.

Comment: This was my initial try! But in the answer section it says n=3.

Comment: I do not think you can make that assumption.

Comment: Then the fruits are allowed to be repeated. ok. will adjust my answer.

Comment: @Xenusi Now, I added the solution for the repeating case. This is a so-called combination with repetition.

Comment: Thanks. How can one calculate the last inequality without a CAS calculator?

Comment: @Xenusi Exactly, as I did above. As $10$ is not a very large number, it is surely expected, that one can find the solution just by considering the binomial coefficients $\binom 54 = 5$ and then $\binom 64 = 15$, which gives already the solution. Because, you have only to solve $6=n+3 \Rightarrow n=3$.

Comment: Just for reference for the last case, if you are not yet acquainted with combinations with repetitions:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: I read the Wiki article. I makes sense!

Comment: For the repeating case